# Serving images for a cakePHP site from a different sub-domain

Tags: image, cakephp, subdomain

what is the best practice for serving images from a different sub-domain(like media.host.com) in cakePHP? Should I put the images in the img folder provided by cakephp and make this folder the document root of the sub-domain, or is there a better way of doing this?

Roland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it matters as long as the images are in the same place. In any case you can't use `$html->image()` as is, or you can but it's probably wiser to modify it or roll your own helper so that you don't have to always give it the full path. While you're doing that you can just make it use whatever url root you want.

Comment: Or you could go the whole hog and write a CDN component and give it back to the community!

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is set IMAGES_URL constant before cake does, or even overload image() in AppHelper. if you are some how using array urls for images you would also need to overload url() in AppHelper

Comment: Setting IMAGES_URL doesn't work because Cake adds a / before the URL.

Answer (score -1):

I personally just created a separate subdomain pointing to the Cake webroot, which would only serve static files (so deny Cake's index.php, for example). A custom webroot() method in AppHelper modifies the URL for every returned webroot path (script(), image() and css() all use this) so no further code changes are needed.

I wrote a short article about it here: http://metaphoric.nl/blog/serving-static-content-from-a-separate-subdomain-in-cakephp